# Django unbound method has_header() must be called with HttpResponseForbidden

Tags: django

I'm getting the following error when implementing `HttpResponseForbidden` in my Django code. The error is:

> unbound method has_header() must be called with HttpResponseForbidden
>   instance as first argument (got unicode instance instead)

Here is my view:

```
def index(request):
    if not settings.DEBUG:
        return HttpResponseForbidden
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling one of the [HttpResponse subclasses](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#httpresponse-subclasses) I needed to remember to call the function with (), i.e., `HttpResponseForbidden()` rather than simply `HttpResponse` without the trailing parentheses.

The proper code is:

```
def index(request):
    if not settings.DEBUG:
        return HttpResponseForbidden()
```